# Running C++ exe file in PowerShell

Tags: c++, windows, powershell, codeblocks

I'm usually not programming in C++, but this time I had to and I've got a problem executing my code in PowerShell (which I have never done before). 
The program is written using CodeBlocks, it works fine. I specify arguments in Project_> Set program arguments and in does what it should, if no arguments are specified it returns an info about that, as it should.

The thing is, I built my program in CodeBlocks, then wanted to run the generated \bin\Program.exe' file in PowerShell. I enter:

```
C:\path\to\Program.exe
```

and nothing happens. I tried that with arguments, still nothing at all. 
I fixed all missing .dll files, but I'm lost. Do I produce the .exe file in a wrong way? Is there any way to fix this issue?

Comment: What happens when you write and then run in powershell an idiotically simple program like Hello World?

Comment: Does the prompt return when you hit enter?

Comment: It does return to prompt. It's just:
prompt> .\Program.exe
prompt>

Comment: Can you run the program from `cmd`?

Comment: What is the program supposed to do when given no arguments? I ask because we don't have the code and we are not sure how you handle this.

Comment: @drescherjm it is suposed to print, that the arguments number is invalid. But it doesn't run with correct arguments either.

Comment: @ravnsgaard the same output, nothing happens.

Comment: Maybe you still have missing dlls or are using the wrong version ( mixing 32 and 64 bit or different version of mingw in the PATH).

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you're in the directory of the executable.

```
cd "C:\path\to\"
```

Then, execute the program as so:

```
.\"Program.exe"
```

Comment: That's what I do. The thing is, the program does nothing. It doesn't execute, dosn't return an error, although it normally should. It's just 'prompt>.\Program.exe (new line) prompt>'

Comment: @n_inspring are you certain that the program is guaranteed an output? What you're describing is normal if it has no output. You press enter, it'll run the program, and when it's closed it'll simply go to the next prompt without confirming that the program ran. To get an output, add `std::cout<<"Program execution\n";` to the start of `main()`. If the program didn't run, you'll get an error stating `The term '.\Program.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program.`